# sed or operator in set of regex

Tags: linux, bash, sed

The bash script I wrote is supposed to modify my text files. The problem is the speed of operation. There are 4 lines of each file I want to modify.

This is my bash script to modify all .txt files in a given folder:

```
srcdir="$1" //source directory
cpr=$2 //given string argument 

find $srcdir -name "*.txt" | while read i; do
    echo "#############################"
    echo "$i"
    echo "Custom string: $cpr"
    echo "#############################"

    # remove document name and title
    sed -i 's_document=.*\/[0-9]\{10\}\(, User=team\)\?__g' $i

    # remove document date
    sed -i 's|document date , [0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{4\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\} MDT||g' $i

    # remove document id
    sed -i 's|document id = 878h67||g' $i

    # replace new producer
    sed_arg="-i 's|Reproduced by $cpr|john smith|g' $i"
    eval sed "$sed_arg"

done
```

I dont know how to concatinate all my `sed` commands in one command or two, so the job would be done faster ( I think! )

I have tried the OR operator for regex `|` but no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
sed -i -e 's/pattern/replacement/g' -e 's/pattern1/replace1/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '
        s_document=.*\/[0-9]\{10\}\(, User=team\)\?__g;
        s|document date , [0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{4\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\} MDT||g;
        s|document id = 878h67||g;
        s|Reproduced by '"$cpr"'|john smith|g' $i
```

Comment: thank you but adding `$cpr` like you said comes with error which was not my question though. thanks again.